# Python 3.6, Pandas Import .csv file, filter and analyze columns, save results to new .csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a .csv file 'Data.csv', and want to import it to Python3.6 using pandas. I want to analyze this data by filtering multiple columns, and save my results to new .csv files with my analyzed data. My 'Data.csv' is separated by ',', and works with loc to filter my columns. If my imported file is comma delimited, can I change this to separate by tab '\t' for the new "filtered" .csv files?

(Running Python 3.6)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', sep = ',')
df1 = df.loc[:, ['STATION',"NAME","DATE","AWND","SNOW"]]
df1["DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE)
df1.to_csv('filteredData.csv', sep=',', header=True)
```

From here, I have my new .csv file with my desired columns and all rows of my data. I want to calculate the averages of each month, and produce two more .csv files by year (2016, and 2017).

```
df2 = df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq="M")).mean()
```

If I understand this correctly, this has grouped my data by the average of each month. How do I further separate each year (2016, and 2017) into its own .csv file and show the results as: NAME, Month, and Average?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Most probably your df is not separated by `\t`  (since only `ix` worked). Can you check output of `df.head()`?

Comment: I made an edit to my original post, the 'Data.csv' file was separated by ',' and that caused the return NaN for fields that had data. Looking to save it to a new CSV file separated by a tab - '\t'

Comment: You can try with separator of `\t` in `to_csv` without using `df1`: `df[['STATION',"NAME","DATE","AWND","SNOW"]].to_csv('filteredData.csv', sep='\t', index=False)`